# Core Data - GROUP BY

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to group results returned by Core Data. I read that you need to use "SortDescriptors" with a selector but I cant seem to get it to work?

I am trying to return group'ed "unique" name values?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html

Comment: Bumping this! If i write "@distinctUnionOfObjects.contactNumber", it returns an array with only contact numbers while i want a Recents object which has both "contactNumber" and "contactName". Any idea how to write the operator so that it would return the Recents object instead of the NSString contactNumber?

Comment: So if i add "distinctUnionOfObjects" as a prefix to the attribute then it returns a distinct array of objects?

Comment: No, it will give a distinct array of the values of that attribute. In my case, it gives an array of contactNumber strings instead of Recents objects where the contactNumber is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using @distinctUnionOfArrays.contactNumber to get the objects

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think you want `@distinctUnionOfObjects`. See the [Xcode Documentation: Key-Value Coding Programming Guide: Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).